# Run a method while another one is running

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, methods

Hello stack overflow community,
this is my first time using this site. So please be kind ^^"
(And sorry for the strange commands, that is a library my school uses. Unfortunately in German)

I wanted to get the movement `if (dieTastatur.rechts()){...` running, while my other method `this.erscheinen();` is doing its job. Is this possible? If not how can I change it to work properly?

Problem is: I can't move the camera while the blocks are moving towards me

```
public void fuehreAus(){

    while(true){

        Klotz_Array[0].unsichtbar();
        Klotz_Array[1].unsichtbar();
        Klotz_Array[2].unsichtbar();
        Klotz_Array[3].unsichtbar();
        this.erscheinen();



        if(dieTastatur.rechts()){
            this.bewege_rechts();
            Sys.warte(3);
        }
        if(dieTastatur.links()){
            this.bewege_links();
            Sys.warte(15);
        }
        if(dieTastatur.oben()){
            this.bewege_oben();
            Sys.warte(3);
        }
        if(dieTastatur.unten()){
            this.bewege_unten();
            Sys.warte(3);
        }
    }

}


 public void bewege_links(){
     if(dieTastatur.links()){
         dieKamera.setzePosition(-150,250,3000);
         for(int a=0;a<=100;a++){
         }
         Sys.warte(400);
         dieKamera.setzePosition(0,250,3000);
     }   
 }

 public void bewege_rechts(){
     if(dieTastatur.rechts()){
         dieKamera.setzePosition(150, 250, 3000);
         for(int a=0;a<=100;a++){
         }
         Sys.warte(400);
         dieKamera.setzePosition(0,250,3000);    
     } 
 }

 public void bewege_oben(){
     if(dieTastatur.oben()){
         dieKamera.setzePosition(0,400,3000);
         dieKamera.setzeBlickpunkt(0,400,-10);
         for(int a=0;a<=100;a++){
         }
         Sys.warte(400);
         dieKamera.setzePosition(0,250,3000);
         dieKamera.setzeBlickpunkt(0,250,-10);
     } 
 }

 public void bewege_unten(){
     if(dieTastatur.unten()){
         dieKamera.setzePosition(0,100,3000);
         for(int a=0;a<=100;a++){
         }
         Sys.warte(400);
         dieKamera.setzePosition(0,250,3000);
     } 
 }

     public void erscheinen(){
        while(!Klotz_Stack.isEmpty()){
            Klotz_Stack.top().bewege();
            Klotz_Stack.pop();
        }
    }
```

And here is the bewege method from "Klotz" class

```
public void bewege(){

    int a = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;

    if(a==1){ 
        Block1.setzeSichtbarkeit(true);
        for(int b=0;b<=1000;b++){
            Block1.verschiebe(0,0,5);
            Sys.warte(3);
        }
        Block1.loesche();
    }
    if(a==2){ 
        Block3.setzeSichtbarkeit(true);
        for(int b=0;b<=1000;b++){
            Block3.verschiebe(0,0,5);
            Sys.warte(3);
        }
        Block3.loesche();
    }
    if(a==3){ 
        Block2.setzeSichtbarkeit(true);
        for(int b=0;b<=1000;b++){
            Block2.verschiebe(0,0,5);
            Sys.warte(3);
        }
        Block2.loesche();
    }
    if(a==4){ 
        Block4.setzeSichtbarkeit(true);
        for(int b=0;b<=1000;b++){
            Block4.verschiebe(0,0,5);
            Sys.warte(3);
        }
        Block4.loesche();
    }


}
public void unsichtbar(){
    Block1.setzeSichtbarkeit(false);
    Block2.setzeSichtbarkeit(false);
    Block3.setzeSichtbarkeit(false);
    Block4.setzeSichtbarkeit(false);
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ <- The Java essentials Tutorial about concurrency, threads etc. might be a good place for you to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the necessary import:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
```

Then you can make your feuhreAus method start a new thread like so and return immediately.

```
public void fuehreAus(){
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                Klotz_Array[0].unsichtbar();
                Klotz_Array[1].unsichtbar();
                Klotz_Array[2].unsichtbar();
                ...
            }
        }
    });
}
```